# How do I start VNC Server on boot?

Tags: autostart

How do I create a system-wide autostart file?  This would be on a cloud server running the desktop version of Maverick.

I logged in as root and created an autostart file using `System/Preferences/StartupApplications` but it ended up in `/root/.config/autostart` and did not execute (as far as I can tell) upon rebooting.  The autostart file is to invoke a bash script that invokes the VNC server.

I copied the .desktop autostart file from `/root/.config/autostart` to `/etc/xdg/autostart` and rebooted.  This did not seem to make a difference.

**Edit** As mentioned in a comment, the objective is to run my bash script which starts the VNC server upon boot; not upon a login.

Comment: do you mean autostart on boot or autostart when someone (anyone) logs on?

Comment: I want the VNC server to autostart on boot.

Comment: I've found an answer at SU SE http://superuser.com/questions/147109/automatically-start-vnc-server-on-startup give it a try

Comment: Doesn't VNC requires a display to run?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. First, install the TightVNC server  `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`.
2. Set up the VNC server for the user you wish to log in as. When you run "vncserver" for the first time, it will ask you to set a password. only allow SSH tunnelled or VPN connections. To launch programs or a session when your VNC session starts, modify `~/.vnc/xstartup`. Here is an example.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
   xsetroot -solid black
   /opt/azureus/azureus &
   k3b &
   icewm-session &
   ```
3. Copy the following into `/etc/init.d/vncserver`. The easiest way to do it is to copy it to your clipboard, run `sudo -i && cat > /etc/init.d/vncserver && exit` in a terminal, paste it in, and type CTRL-D. Be sure to change the USER variable to whatever user you want the VNC server to run under.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          vncserver
   # Required-Start:    networking
   # Default-Start:     3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      0 6
   ### END INIT INFO

   PATH="$PATH:/usr/X11R6/bin/"

   # The Username:Group that will run VNC
   export USER="mythtv"
   #${RUNAS}

   # The display that VNC will use
   DISPLAY="1"

   # Color depth (between 8 and 32)
   DEPTH="16"

   # The Desktop geometry to use.
   #GEOMETRY="<WIDTH>x<HEIGHT>"
   #GEOMETRY="800x600"
   GEOMETRY="1024x768"
   #GEOMETRY="1280x1024"

   # The name that the VNC Desktop will have.
   NAME="my-vnc-server"

   OPTIONS="-name ${NAME} -depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY}"

   . /lib/lsb/init-functions

   case "$1" in
   start)
   log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on   localhost:${DISPLAY}"
   su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS}"
   ;;

   stop)
   log_action_begin_msg "Stoping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISPLAY}"
   su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY}"
   ;;

   restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
   ;;
   esac

   exit 0
   ```
4. Make the script executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver`.
5. Finally, connect to your server with a VNC client on port 590X, where X is the value of "DISPLAY" in the vncserver script. On OS X, I like to use Chicken of the VNC. On Windows and Linux, the TightVNC client works nicely.

<sub>[Source](http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot)</sub>

Comment: This http://superuser.com/questions/147109/automatically-start-vnc-server-on-startup from wisemonkey is the stackexchange equivalent answer. It works. Note the path to X11 might need adjusting.

Comment: TigerVNC installs `/etc/init.d/vncserver` which starts all vncservers configured in `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers`

Comment: This was copy-pasted from http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot, but it LEFT OUT THE MOST IMPORTANT STEP `sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults`

Comment: Since this solution is accepted, can you detail whether the described steps are "only allowing tunnel SSH or VPN connections" ? Or was this a prerequisite? @maniat1k13

Answer (score 3):

One possibility: /etc/rc.local

The content says it:

```
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits. 
#
# By default this script does nothing
```

The execution bits are set to 755 on my system already. (chmod 755 /etc/rc.local)

You can put any command in there, which will be executed as root.

This is ok for your purpose as long as you do not change runlevels, I guess. (If you do not know what runlevels are, nevermind).

Comment: This suggestion did not work for me.

Comment: [These 2 tweaks](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/882254/comments/3) may help.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman, thank you but those 2 tweaks did not work.

Answer (score 3):

this seems to be an old post but the topic might be still interesting for some users.  To have vnc to start at boot up, you will need to

1. install a vnc server software (here we will be using x11vnc)
2. configure a startup script (used to start the vnc service)

Step 1 - install x11vnc server

from a command line, type

```
 sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

To add security, you should set a pwd

```
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd
```

Step 2 - Configure your startup script

- if your ubuntu version is lower 15.04,

you create the config file under `/etc/init.d/x11vnc.conf` and populate it with the correct commands to be executed

```
start on login-session-start  
script  
/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -auth
/var/run/lightdm/root/:0
-noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage 
-rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass 
-forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log  
end script
```

- if your ubuntu version is 15.04 or later,

these systems are using systemd and you will need to create your service unit file under `/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service`  and populate it with the correct commands to be executed

```
[Unit] Description=Start x11vnc at startup. After=multi-user.target

[Service] Type=simple ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever
-loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/USERNAME/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared

[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload the service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
```

You can find detailed information on Help Ubuntu Community wiki page (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Have_x11vnc_start_automatically_via_systemd_in_any_environment_.28Vivid.2B-.29)) or you can try to use this quick to use recipice

- For Ubuntu version **lower than 15.04**, check [this post](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5870)
- For Ubuntu version **15.04 or later**, check [this post](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8361)

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TigerVNC then it installs `/etc/init.d/vncserver` which starts all vncservers configured in `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers`
E.g. following would start 2 instances on display 1 & 2 at start up.

```
# <display>:<user>
VNCSERVERS="1:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1920x1080"

VNCSERVERS="2:guest"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -SecurityTypes None"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the below line to crontab file. This means the command after the keyword `@reboot` gets executed during very reboot.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/vncserver :1
```

To open crontab file, need to use the command `crontab -e`

Comment: Same as this 6-year-old answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/124079/158442

Answer (score 0):

You can have cron start stuff for you at boot time.  Just use the string "@reboot" in place of the numbers that you normally use to specify when the thing should run.

For example, here's how I start Dropbox on a machine on which it doesn't otherwise start automatically:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot         /usr/bin/dropbox start
```

Comment: [This page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/) says that only works if the system actually reboots (no cold boot).

Answer (score 0):

'sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults' reported that there was missing;
"Required-Stop:" (even empty). So I added it like below. And no more warning.

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          vncserver
    # Required-Start:    networking
    # Required-Stop:     
    # Default-Start:     3 4 5
    # Default-Stop:      0 6
    ### END INIT INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's stumbling across this in current year 2024, the accepted answer works, however x11vnc may not be the best server package to use as it closes the server once the client disconnects.

I recommend instead `tightvncserver` - it takes some tinkering but [this tutorial by DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-debian-11#step-4-running-vnc-as-a-system-service) (step 4) has a much better method for creating a daemon to run `tightvncserver` in the background and on startup.

Some notes: don't use `xfce4` - it will run a weird Debian skin in the remote window instead of your OS. Using the default `xserver` file should work fine.