# Using Remmina between two Ubuntu 14.04 Systems

Tags: 14.04, vnc, rdp, remmina

I have a laptop and desktop running 14.04. I want to use Remmina to access either system depending on where I am. I want to be able to access them even when the other system  is at the login screen.

I can access them using the VNC setting but not when a system is at the login screen. The response is "Unable to Connect to VNC Server". Presumably it is not started until after a login. Is there a setting for it to run all the time?

Is it not possible to use RDP between the two systems? I have connected to a Raspberry Pi using RDP but do not know what server it runs. Also to Windows XP. A reason for running RDP is to control the resolution of the remote system on the host monitors because the laptop has wide display. I tried xrdp but all I got was a funny white with black screen with a big X in the middle.

Comment: I see from another question that XRDP will not work with GNOME or DASH desktops so you can ignore that part of the question. The PI must be running a compatible desktop. http://askubuntu.com/questions/449785/ubuntu-14-04-xrdp-grey

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I start VNC Server on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120973/how-do-i-start-vnc-server-on-boot)

Answer (score 0):

you have two options here

usin

- using xRDP software (but you need to install and additional desktop environment such as mate,xfce,....).  This alternate desktop will be used by xRDP software as xRDP on Ubuntu does not work with gnome or Unity
- Configure your system to have the vncserver started at boot up so the service will be available to be used for you

To have a detailed step by step process, you can have a look at the following posts [x11vnc at startup](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5870)