# vncserver in rc.local start-up password?

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

I have tried the answer here that suggests using x11vnc:
[How do I start VNC Server on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120973/how-do-i-start-vnc-server-on-boot)
Didn't work for me.

I have tried this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/147109/automatically-start-vnc-server-on-startup
Didn't Work for me.

I have tried this answer to start up the service by adding vncserver to rc.local
http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Run-VNC-on-boot.html

My goal is to have a vncserver that I can connect to on system start-up for a headless NAS. After getting the vncserver starting with rc.local, I am now able to see the server to connect via RealVNC Viewer. I now I have the problem of what password it is configured for and how can I change it?

I have tried the password configured in the x11vnc -storepasswd command, but that hasn't worked. I've tried most of the other passwords that it could possibly be, and none of them have worked either.

Answer (score 0):

I've used two different techniques that allow a user to connect using their ID.  XRPD provides more flexibility in desktop sizing, as the size is specified at connect time, but requires an RDP client.  Running XDMCP provides a fixed desktop size (per port), but works with VNC clients.  I've documented my process in my block posting on [Remote Desktops with VNC and RDP](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/).

If I remember correctly from experimenting with your setup, you may need to specify the location of the password file.  You also need to do some extra configuration so that the desktop is not running as root.

If you want to use the techniques you have found, the password(s) should be in the $HOME/.vnc/password.  $HOME is the home directory of the user you are starting VNC as.  Try `man vncpassword`, `man vncserver` and `man Xvnc` for more details.  You can alter the password file location with the `-rfauth`.  Directory permissions must be 700 and the directory owned by the user running the vncserver.

Try to get the server running from an ssh session before starting it automatically. This should allow you to get some better diagnostics.

Comment: From someone who doesn't know Linux systems very well, that looks like a lot of work from the quick read that I did for the link.

To address the second point, I went through several iterations of finding, removing, and recreating the password file. Still no luck.

Comment: @robodonkey It may look like a lot of work but you only need to set one solution up.  You'll need some basic xwindows software anyway.